# How to add value to each Item in QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox

I'm working with `QComboBox` in `PyQt5`. I want each item in the `QComboBox` to hold a value. To demonstrate my idea, I have 3 items in my `firstC` that are named `USD, EUR, BGN`

I want each of the items to have a value, like example `USD` to be able to `print('1')` on the console, the second item to (`EUR`) `print('2')` and so on...

My idea behind this is, when an Item in the `QComboBox` is selected, to hold a value.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into QComboBox's "ItemData" methods?
You can use `combobox.setItemData(intex, value[, role])` and similary `getItemData` and `itemData`